# How to set current page size in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

How to set current page height and width from within JavaScript?

I am using ASP.Net Web Forms. I have some splash screens implemented as aspx web forms. I need to just redirect them and not to open by window.open() function.

How do I give size and position to current window?
I have tried the below code, but it did not work for me

```
<body style="margin:0px;width:600px; height:90%;" >
```

Comment: You want to define the dimensions of the current window (browser) ? If so, it's not possible.

Comment: So, that's impossible. Just think about a web where every site could resize user's browser...

Comment: Have you tried this:  <body onload="window.resizeTo(600,800)">

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    document.body.style.width = '600px'
    document.body.style.height= '900px'
});
```

or if you are using jQuery...

```
 $(function() {
         $('body').css('width', '600px');
    $('body').css('height', '900px');
    });
```

Comment: Some time for height % is not working , instead if we use px . It will work.If you like the comment then upvote it.

Comment: did the body tag is closed?

Comment: did you write this code inside of here?`$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});`

Comment: You can use it by 90% to 900px. i have updated my answer. It's wroking to me

Comment: Resizing the body won't change window size.

Answer (score 0):

**Resizing the current window of the browser is actually impossible.** That can only be done by the user (fortunatly :) )

You can set dimensions to a new window, with `window.open();`, but that's all.

As I said in comment : *Just think about a web where every site could resize user's browser...*

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to control width of body. Rather, you can use a  inside your body and outside your content, and then set width, height and position of that .

Also, to set height of that  in percentages, you will need to apply height:100% to both html and body in CSS.

So, your content could look like,

```
<html>
  .....
  <body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    .....
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and your css can look like,

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper
{
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto; /* to center the div */
  margin-right: auto; /* to center the div */
  height: 90%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```